# Why does neither one of my texts get displayed

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The code down below shows my work in react, where i freshly startet my project and i am still pretty new in this kind of area. I have one simple question that i am just cant comprehend. Its probalby something simple. I expected the h1 with the text Hi too get rendered or to get foo as output, but my website isnt showing any text at all

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (

    
    <div className='App'>
      <h1> Hi </h1>
      
      <>
      
      <Router>
        <Navbar/>
          <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact/>
          </Routes>
      </Router>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js

```
import './Navbar.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className='navbar'>
        <div className='navbar-container'>
            <Link to="/" >foo</Link>
        </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

After further testing it has shown that when i delete everything in the return function of App.js except the h1 Hi gets rendered.

Comment: what is url u r trying ?

Comment: can you elaborate your question further?

Comment: I copied down each file and it worked fine. Hi and foo get shown. My assumptions are toward CSS so.

Comment: I recomend you install the Chrome React Developer tools so you can debug more easily https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Comment: i dont really know what should be wrong with the css part, there isnt really much to do wrong, is it

Comment: Hi Gollasso, please put this in code in jsfiddle or codepen, so that people can see exactly what you need. State clearly what issue you are having, right now it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working properly now. The issue was that i installed react-router-dom one folder above the normal rreact app so that i had two seperate package.json files. I've uninstalled react-router-dom and reinstalled it in the same folder of the react folder. The json files got merged and then it worked after reloading

Answer (score 0):

I am gussing probably this is the issue. You are using React <18 and trying to use `createRoot` which is not there.

Change

```
//Don't use below because it's in React 18
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

to

```
let rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pagkyw